# handle solr facet result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have a diagram like:
[image]

and i have

```
"city_id":[
        "1",131,
        "2",96,
        "3",11,
        "4",10,
        "7",8,
        "6",6,
        "15",5,
        "10",4,
        "34",4,
        "36",3,
        "59",3,
        "71",1]},
```

In quotes is city_id and on the right is the job count of that city

I want to process them into a hash like this

```
{:region_1=> 
{["city_name", "slug"]=>jobs count,
["city_name", "slug"]=>jobs count,
["city_name", "slug"]=>jobs count},
:region_2=> 
{["city_name", "slug"]=>jobs count,
["city_name", "slug"]=>jobs count,
["city_name", "slug"]=>jobs count},
...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with slug? And for what is it used?

Comment: I have updated my question. It's just a column in the City table

Comment: Index the city name and slug on the job documents instead, as a combined field if necessary, and you can just extract it directly from your facet.

Comment: @MatsLindh Can you give more instructions. I'm just getting used to solr

Comment: When you need specific combinations, it's usually better to add those combinations as separate fields to the index when you're indexing your documents, instead of trying to create them later. So in this case you'd create a separate field that contains the information you need, for example a field named `cityname_slug` with `cityname|slug` as its content. You then facet across that field instead, and get both the cityname and the slug in the result - and split it on `|` in your frontend when displaying the key.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cleanest way to do, but it could work:

```
final_hash = {}
Hash[*city_id.flatten(1)].each do |city_id, job_count|
  city = City.find(city_id)
  region = city.region
  slug = city.slug
  city_name = city.name
  final_hash[region] = Hash.new unless final_hash.key?(region)
  final_hash[region][[city_name, slug]] = job_count
end
```

This makes your strange arraylist to a hash:

```
Hash[*city_id.flatten(1)]
```